# Sequelize join table through foreign keys not created

Tags: join, express, many-to-many, sequelize.js

I am trying to create a user > friend relationship in sequelize. Therefore, I created a user model and a belongsToMany relationship through a join-table called friends. It created the table but the foreignKeys userId and friendId are not created. I would be happy if someone could help me out.

User model:

```
var User = sequelize.define('user', {
    id: {
      type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
      autoIncrement: true,
      primaryKey: true
    },
    emailaddress: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING
    },
    firstname: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING
    },
    lastname: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING
    },
    description: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING
    },
    password: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING
    }
  }, {
    freezeTableName: true, 
    classMethods: {
      associate: function (models) {
        User.belongsToMany(models.user, {
          as: "user",
          through: "friend"
        });
        User.belongsToMany(models.user, {
          as: "friend",
          through: "friend"
        });
        User.sync({
            force: true
          })
      }
    }
  });
```

friend model

```
var Friend = sequelize.define('friend', {
    // userId: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    // friendId: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    status: {
      type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
      defaultValue: 0
    }
  }, {
    freezeTableName: true,
    classMethods: {
      associate: function (models) {
        Friend.sync()
      }
    }
  });
```

This generates the following field in the friend table:

> id  status createdAt updatedAt

I would like the following fields:

> id status userId friendId createdAt updatedAt

package.json > "sequelize": "^3.17.1",

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some debugging I found out that the problem was that I called Table.sync on initializing every table instead of doing it just once when all tables are defined (see the example code in the sequelize express example on github: https://github.com/sequelize/express-example). This corrupted the table creation process.

Answer (score 2):

You can set `otherKey` and `foreignKey` to a sequelize associations. I think you should try this:

```
User.belongsToMany(models.user, {
    as: "friends",
    through: "friend",
    otherKey: 'userId',
    foreignKey: 'friendId'
});
```

Sorry I can't try it right now, but I hope, it helps you.

Comment: I tried it out and I came to the conclusion that it did not solve my problem, although it is a nice way to achieve the same result. My problem was the fact that I call User.sync directly when initializing every table, when I removed the sync from every table and only did one sync, using the sequelize express example code (I am using express) it worked.

Comment: I would still like to assign to you the 100 bounty because your answer pointed me in the right direction. update: will be dealt with in 2 hours. I am not allowed to award it yet ;)